# How to insert values to newly added column

Tags: oracle

I am new to oracle thus this question.

There is a table already existed and I have added a new column to it.
There are 5 rows and I do not want to use update table with where clause to insert the values one by one in the new column. Is there a statement like INSERT ALL to insert the values into the new column in one shot ?

Thanks

Comment: INSERT will only do insert i.e. append records to the existing record set so in effect you will have 10 records (5 old + 5 new) after trying to insert for empty column. You can only update for existing row-set.

Comment: Which values do you want to put into that newly added column? The same? Different? Based on some condition?

Comment: You cannot `insert` a data into a column, because in SQL tables are of the 1'st normal form and columns store *values*. Use `update` to **set** a value for a column or describe why do you think it's not sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use something like below which in-effect I would say is multiple update only, wrapped in single statement.

```
SQL> select * from test_upd;

       ID1        ID2
---------- ----------
         1
         2
         3
         4

SQL> update test_upd a set a.id2 =
  2  (select
  3  case
  4  when id1=1 then 100
  5  when id1=2 then 200
  6  when id1=3 then 300
  7  else 5000 end
  8  from test_upd b
  9  where a.id1=b.id1);

4 rows updated.

SQL> select * from test_upd;

       ID1        ID2
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200
         3        300
         4       5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO your_table dst
USING (
  SELECT 1 AS id, 'aaa' AS newvalue FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'ccc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'ddd' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'eee' FROM DUAL
) src
ON (dst.id = src.id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET value = src.newvalue;
```

Which, if you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (id, value) AS
SELECT 1, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, NULL FROM DUAL;
```

Then, after the `MERGE`, the table contains:

> | ID | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | aaa |
> | 2 | bbb |
> | 3 | ccc |
> | 4 | ddd |
> | 5 | eee |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d10e9fc3683759e3a1ad6f6ebb93cecb)*